Parsing Spotify Web API results with JSONata in iOS shortcuts
I'm trying to get the results from a JSONata expression to print out using HTML and Javascript, but I'm not having any luck. The expression works in the JSONata playground and produces the array I expect, but I don't get any output when I include it in a javascript function.
Here is the expression I wrote:
items.{"Release Year":$number(($toMillis($.track.album.release_date))~>$fromMillis('[Y]')),"Track":track.name,"Artist(s)":$join($map(track.artists.name,$string),", "),"Album":track.album.name,"Genre":"","URL":$join(['https://song.link/s/',track.id]),"Release Date":track.album.release_date,"Duration":track.duration_ms,"Popularity":track.popularity,"SpotifyID":track.id,"Added to Playlist On":$toMillis($.added_at)~>$fromMillis('[M]/[D]/[Y] at [h]:[m] [P]')}

This expression is used in the following HTML. Because this is an iOS shortcut, the variable apiResponse2 is filled through a different series of commands. I know I'm getting the appropriate response from the API:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata/jsonata.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<script>

var jsonata = require("jsonata");
function evaluateJsonata() {
    var apiData = apiResponse2;
    var expression = jsonata(items.{"Release Year":$number(($toMillis($.track.album.release_date))~>$fromMillis('[Y]')),"Track":track.name,"Artist(s)":$join($map(track.artists.name,$string),", "),"Album":track.album.name,"Genre":"","URL":$join(['https://song.link/s/',track.id]),"Release Date":track.album.release_date,"Duration":track.duration_ms,"Popularity":track.popularity,"SpotifyID":track.id,"Added to Playlist On":$toMillis($.added_at)~>$fromMillis('[M]/[D]/[Y] at [h]:[m] [P]')});
    var result = expression.evaluate(apiData);
    document.write(JSON.stringify(result)) 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

You can see a sample of the JSON returned by the Spotify API at this link. The API JSON is also in the JSONata playground.
Because this is an iOS shortcut, I post the above in a text block, then do the following:
Screenshot of Used Shortcut Actions
But, I don't get the expected array back. In fact, I get nothing back. I'm hoping my error is with the Javascript.
Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Have you tried to properly encode the > contained in that expression, as &gt; for the HTML context you are putting it into?

If you mean "properly encode," then I believe so. The "encode, base 64" action is run on the text block and that encode is then passed to form the url. Does the javascript look right to you? I've thought about moving the script to Scriptable and seeing if I get a different result.

No, I meant exactly what I wrote. > has special meaning in HTML, so when you just want it to be the literal character >, then it needs to be written as &gt;

Understood. I tried enclosing the offending expression with CDATA or encoding it as you suggested but I'm still unable to get a response.

Your above code put into a fiddle gives me an error because it doesn't like items.{ - which is indeed not valid JS syntax. I'm guessing maybe the whole expression you pass into jsonata(...) might need to be a string? Can't really tell, because after making that modification, it of course alerts me the require doesn't exist in this browser context to begin with.

Yes, it appears every single example under https://docs.jsonata.org/embedding-extending indeed passes the expression as a string value.

You were onto something. Backticks is what ultimately worked. Thanks so much for the help.

Try making your function asynchronous and await the evaluate method like so:
async function evaluateJsonata() {
    var apiData = apiResponse2;
    var expression = jsonata(`items.{"Release Year":$number(($toMillis($.track.album.release_date))~>$fromMillis('[Y]')),"Track":track.name,"Artist(s)":$join($map(track.artists.name,$string),", "),"Album":track.album.name,"Genre":"","URL":$join(['https://song.link/s/',track.id]),"Release Date":track.album.release_date,"Duration":track.duration_ms,"Popularity":track.popularity,"SpotifyID":track.id,"Added to Playlist On":$toMillis($.added_at)~>$fromMillis('[M]/[D]/[Y] at [h]:[m] [P]')}`);
    var result = await expression.evaluate(apiData);
    document.write(JSON.stringify(result)) 
}

Remove the require call because it works in node.js only. The browser will automatically import the package from the script tag.

Remember to wrap the jsonata expression in backticks so it becomes a string.

Call the evaluateApiResponse() at the bottom.


I tried that, but I'm still not able to get a response. The JSFiddle console shows an error that reads "1659:38 SyntaxError: missing name after . operator." There is no line 1659, column 38, no so help there.

I got it working in the JSFiddle you provided and I've updated my answer with further instructions and images. Let me know if it works.

Thank you so much. This was driving me up a wall. I suspected one of my mistakes revolved around syntax errors. One of the commenters pointed that out above. I don't see any mention of backticks in the documentation, and I've forgotten most of what I knew about JavaScript work. Thanks again.
